# Looking for a free e-book related to Architecting Enterprise Applications using .NET

Tags: .net, architecture, enterprise

Could you please suggest me some good free e-books related to Architecting Enterprise Applications using .NET ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Give a look to this book:

- [patterns & practices Application Architecture Guide 2.0](http://www.codeplex.com/AppArchGuide)

  [book cover http://i3.codeplex.com/Project/Download/FileDownload.aspx?ProjectName=AppArchGuide&DownloadId=52040](http://i3.codeplex.com/Project/Download/FileDownload.aspx?ProjectName=AppArchGuide&DownloadId=52040)

Comment: CMS, Thank you very much....
Meanwhile, do you have below e-book:
" Microsoft® .NET: Architecting Applications for the Enterprise "

Answer (score 3):

you can have a good look at what CMS has suggested. that's a good one.

also you can look at the below, for some good essays, blogs and practical steps in [Coding the architecture](http://www.codingthearchitecture.com/pages/book/index.html). this is for any generic architecture.

Answer (score 2):

Not really a book, but if you can read the code it's ok: the [Northwind Starter Kit sample application](http://nsk.codeplex.com/). It is a concrete implementation of many enterprise design patterns.